AWS amplify shows a white screen just after successful deployment
The whole code has been seen working properly, the deployment has been done successfully. the front and backend deployment works fine, but when I tried to access the deployed api domain "https://main.d3td3qxr7rh3ge.amplifyapp.com", it shows white screen, even everything works fine
I have attached the file names of my project. don't know which file modification can rectify the error. enter image description hereenter image description here.
I tried redeploying the code with the latest build but still showed the same error.
other than that I have no idea what to do and how to rectify or which file should I access.
